# Invalid literal in decimal module for python

Tags: python, floating-point, tk-toolkit

Well it all begun with the infamous floating point weirdness. I'm making a simple chess clock and since in chess seconds often become important, I want to update the clock every 0.01 second. That's why I don't use int variables. I tried doing it with float variables, but it's really annoying for a player to see 31.2899999999999999 instead of just 31.29. Then googling this issue brought me to the decimal module, which looks cool and seems to be a solution, but now I'm receiving the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1475, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "/Users/maciek/Documents/chessclock/chessclock2.py", line 8, in player1move
x=float(player2.get())
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/tkinter/__init__.py", line 313, in get
return getint(self._tk.globalgetvar(self._name))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '29.21'
```

I think it's noteworthy that the first move, when both players have 30 seconds, works well. I don't include the code for player2move function since its analogical. Aside from fixes to my decimal use, I'm also open to any other idea how to make floating values appear properly (for a human eye, that is, I guess for a computer 31.2899999999999999 *is* the proper value).
Here's my code:

```
from decimal import *
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import time

def player1move(*args):
    getcontext().prec = 6
    x=float(player2.get())
    x=Decimal(x)
    while x>0:
        time.sleep(0.01)
        x=x-Decimal('0.01')
        player1.set(Decimal(x))
        root.update()

root = Tk()
root.title("Python Chessclock 2.0")

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

player1 = IntVar()
player1.set(Decimal(30))
ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=player1).grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=(W))
ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=player2).grid(column=3, row=1, sticky=(E))

root.bind('p', player1move)
root.mainloop()
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the traceback more carefully you'll notice that the exception has nothing to do with the `decimal` module but with the call to  `getint` in `tkinter`.

Also and FWIW you don't have to use `decimal` at all if all you want is a nice string representation of a float - just use Python's string formating features.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why I kept trying with IntVar() instead of just StringVar(). And I want to use decimal because it also provides other handy methods I'd like to use, and is more precise I guess.